# Regex implicit AND is not working but explicit OR does

Tags: regex

I got a json string that I want to test with an regex:

string:

> {"complete":true,"dateCompleted":1533718801871,"dateCreated":1533718800064,"detailedStatus":null,"executing":false,"failedOps":0,"failureReason":null,"opsCompleted":11,"opsExpected":null,"progress":null,"returnValue":null,"serverId":"lvt-guwccb-j013","startDate":1533718801613,"starting":false,"startingOrExecuting":false,"success":true,"type":"ActivityEsc"}

I want to find out if one of the fields complete or success are false. To achive that, i want to combine two expressions:

```
("complete":)(?=true)
```

and

```
("success":)(?=true)
```

As far as I read, I would expect just to write both after another, so implicitly they would be treated as AND.

If I use the or (|) operator between the expressions, i get a match, thats kind of weird to me.
Any suggestions?

Comment: Your expectation is wrong "I would expect just to write both after another, so implicitly they would be treated as AND."
If you combine these two with OR like so `(("complete":)(?=true)|("success":)(?=true))` you will get 0 match if both are false, 1 match if one is true and 2 matches if both are two. I think you can work with that. Also, you don't need look ahead for this. It's better for performance to avoid when you can: `(("complete":false)|("success":false))` https://regex101.com/r/j78WE2/1

Comment: Not really, I need to have a query that is having no matches when one of both are false. This is because I am using a java framework where the query returns true or false when the result has more than 1 match...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use below simple regex for your case:

```
("complete":)(?=true).+("success":)(?=true)
```

so if the above statement gives false that means either of complete/success is false else it will give you true.

Comment: Still no need for lookahead.

Comment: @marekful Thank you for inputs. we also no need to look before :)